# How to Determine Swift Inferred Type in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, swift

Say I have something like

`let a = <some-complicated-expression>`

Is there any way within Xcode to check which type the compiler has inferred for `a`?

**EDIT**: \

For example, in the Eclipse Scala IDE, by hovering over the variable name the editor would show the inferred type

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes. Alt click the variable and you'll get a pop over with the type.

[image]

Comment: The same counts for function parameters. Would be nice to have this as a hover info ...

Comment: That's option-click on a mac.